# 98 Honda Accord loss of power

Tags: engine, transmission, accord, acceleration, power-loss

A couple times now in my 1998 Honda Accord I have been driving down the highway when all of a sudden my RPMs drop to idle rates and pressing the gas pedal doesn't rev the engine.  The first time this occurred I pulled over and after a few seconds everything was fine.  The second time I pulled over and the engine died and would not start back.  But after a few minutes it started back up with no problems and I was able to drive it on home.  I have only owned this car since September (trying to avoid a car payment) and it has had a check engine light on since I bought it, that I have not had checked yet.  Also the transmission shifts hard to second gear.  I have never had a car act this way and wondering if this could caused by the transmission. Or if anyone knows what the issue is.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You really need to get the codes checked ... this should be the first thing in your diagnosis. It's really hard to tell you what might be going on with the car without them. There are a ton of reasons it could be doing what it's doing, but getting the codes should help you get them narrowed down.